# batch normalization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I've read a lot about batch normalization and how it is implemented. But I couldn't understand when to use batch normalization or not. What should we notice about the Convolutional Neural Network to know that a batch normalization would give us an improvement on the accuracy?

Comment: Can you provide any context for this? What are you talking about? What does "CNN" stand for here?

Comment: I'm sorry. It stands for Convolutional Neural Network. I've edited the question.

Comment: This still needs some setup to get people on the same page as you. Can you provide some context? Eg, I bet "batch normalization" is different in different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has become quite a common practice to use batch normalization as they are robust to bad initialization. You can read more about what problem batch normalization solves from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).

You can also read more about the practical aspects of batch normalization from the Karpathy DL [course](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#batchnorm) which mentions-

> A recently developed technique by Ioffe and Szegedy called Batch
>   Normalization alleviates a lot of headaches with properly initializing
>   neural networks by explicitly forcing the activations throughout a
>   network to take on a unit gaussian distribution at the beginning of
>   the training. The core observation is that this is possible because
>   normalization is a simple differentiable operation. In the
>   implementation, applying this technique usually amounts to insert the
>   BatchNorm layer immediately after fully connected layers (or
>   convolutional layers, as we’ll soon see), and before non-linearities.